# Double click on Disabled radio button is initiating click event in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, click, internet-explorer-11

Is there any workaround to prevent the click on disabled radio button if it is in disabled mode.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).dblclick(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
});
```

I tried the above code but still `ondblclick` event is initiating on my radio button in disabled mode.

Comment: Can you post jsfiddle link. Cuz I have tried what you provided and it isn't firing event see http://jsfiddle.net/hck94sr5/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented following fiddle.Hope it helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
    $('#test').prop('disabled',true);
   
   // document.getElementById('test').disabled=true;
   $('#test').dblclick(function (e) {
       
        if(e.target.disabled==true)
        return;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log("test");
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="radio"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css to avoid clicking on radio button

```
.avoid-clicks {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: you can prevent the click on disable one also . when you are disbable the radio button add class there and write the css